# Topology Question: Compact Hausdorff Spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness

If $T$ and $T′$ are two distinct compact Hausdorff topologies on $X$, what can we say about $(X,T \cap T′)$ (we know that $T\cap T′$ is a topology on $X$). Is it compact? Is it Hausdorff?

Comment: It is definitely compact since any topology coarser than compact topology is itself compact.

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Hausdorff_Topology_is_Minimal_Hausdorff

Answer (score 6):

It seems the following.

As remarked user87690, the space $(X,T\cap T′)$ is compact. Suppose that the space $(X,T\cap T′)$ is Hausdorff. Then since the identity maps from $(X,T)$ and $(X,T')$ to $(X,T\cap T')$ are continuous, both of them are identity homeomorhisms. Therefore $T=T'$.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, if you know the result that states:

"If $X$ is Hausdorff under topology $T_2$ and compact under a finer topology $T_1$, then $T_1=T_2"$, (see [1])

which can be restated as:

"If $(X,T)$ is a compact Hausdorff space then we cannot make $T$ finer without losing compactness, nor coarser without losing Hausdorff-ness",

then it follows that $(X,T\cap T')$ cannot be Hausdorff if $T\ne T'$.

[1] J. D. Pryce "Basic Methods of Linear Functional Analysis"